# How to add onclick event in dynamicly add html code via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to add some list element in loop via JS. Every element `<li>`contains `<a>` tag, now I want to add onClick event in every adding `<a>` tag. I try to do it so:

```
liCode = '<li><a href="#">Text using variable foo: ' + foo + '</a></li>';
$('#list').append(function() {
    return $(liCode).on('click', clickEventOccurs(foo));
});
```

In `clickEventOccurs` I just output to console foo. It works in strange way: this event performed just on init when every  tag is adding to list, but after click on `<a>` doesn`t perform anything. How to make it works in proper way - on click performed code in clickEventOccurs?

Comment: You can add `onclick="your_function()"` to the `<a>` tag in the string.

Comment: but I can solve problem how to add to the tag onClick="my_function(foo)", where foo is the variable in JS. It showing me error in parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you are assigning not a callback function, but a result of function evaluation. In right way it should be like this:

```
$('#list').append(function() {
    return $(liCode).click(function() {
        clickEventOccurs(foo);
    });
});
```

Also, as you are using jQuery you might use benefits of events delegation and use `.on` method this way:

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li', function() {
    return clickEventOccurs(foo);
});
```

Comment: First code snippet works well, thanks, but now there is other problem, on aby element click I see value of foo as it was on last loop iteration, but not specific value foo every element. I even try to pass simply number of iteration var i, which increments on every iteration, but still on click I see only last value of i, but not value showing number of iteration on which this event was added to list element.

Comment: i'd suggest you searching for some information about JS closures, there's a bunch of similar questions even on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is good for handling events, even to elements which will be created dynamically.

```
$('body').on('click', '#list li', function(){
    clickEventOccurs(foo);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/lnplnp/uGJnc/

HTML :

```
<ol id="list">
  <li><a href="#">Text using variable foo: foovalue</a></li>
</ol>
```

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY :

```
function appending(foo) {
    liCode = '<li><a href="#">Text using variable foo: ' + foo + '</a></li>';
    $('#list').append($(liCode));
}

$('#list').on('click', 'li', function() {
    return clickEventOccurs($("a", this).text());
});

function clickEventOccurs(v){
    console.log(v.split(":")[1].trim());
}

appending("foo1");
appending("foo2");
appending("foo3");
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a variable to that function you'll have to make a second anonymous one, otherwise your clickEventOccurs function will be called at assignment, not as a callback.

```
$('#list').append(function() {
    return $(liCode).click(function() {
      clickEventOccurs(foo)
    });
});
```